# k8s Deployment set readOnly in volumes vs volumeMounts

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I want to utilize data from a persistent volume as `readOnly` inside a container.
What is the difference of setting the `readOnly` flag under the `volumeMounts` vs the deployment `volumes.persistentVolumeClaim`?

The results seems to be the same. Is one of the two redundant?

```yaml
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: ${ORDERER_ORG_NAME}-delpoyment
  namespace: ${NS}
  labels:
    app: ${ORDERER_ORG_NAME}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ${ORDERER_ORG_NAME}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ${ORDERER_ORG_NAME}
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: prepare-tls-certs
          image: busybox
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["/bin/sh", "wait-for-certs.sh"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: fabric-volume
              mountPath: ${ORDERER_ORG_PATH}
              subPath: var/hyperledger/config/tls
              readOnly: true
      containers: # other containers
      volumes:
        - name: fabric-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            readOnly: true
            claimName: fabric-pvc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, yes, the outcome is the same. But this functionality is not redundant, because the `readOnly` on a volume and `readOnly` on a `mountPoint` have different implications. For example,

1. `readOnly: true` on a `volumeMount` means that the `ro` mount option is set when mounting your endpoint. This is on the `container level`. You can read more about `mount options` [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT_MOUNT_OPTIONS).
2. `readOnly: true` on a volume means the ***volume*** is readonly. Even if you don't mount it as `readOnly`, you cannot write to it. This is on a pod level and any container that will mount this volume will not have the ability to write. However, it doesn't ***have to be*** `readOnly`. You can set `readOnly:false` as well, where your `volume` will be `writeable` but the mounted `filesystem` can be `readOnly`. This way, other containers can mount this volume as `readOnly: false` and be able to write to it. This can be used, for instance, to ensure certain containers are not allowed to modify a volume, but others are.

To take it a level further "down the stack", you can have `PersistentVolumes` that can be shared across multiple pods (across multiple nodes). Here, the `readOnly` field plays a role in conjunction with the `AccessMode` of the `PersistentVolume`. You can have an `AccessMode` of `WriteOnceReadMany` meaning that 1 `node` can have pods attaching this volume for `writing` and many can `read` from it only. More than 1 `node` will not be able to have its pods write to this volume. You can read more about `AccessModes` of `PersistentVolumes` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

In summary, the permissions are always `AND`ed together with the most restrictive permission generally `up the stack`. So, generally, an `AccessMode` will be more permissive, a `Volume` permission will be less permissive and the `volumeMount` permissions will be least permissive by design. That's the way you design access to your resources.

Comment: thank you. this clears things a lot. The reference material is also informative. Didn't expect to read a Linux man page on a k8s related answer, but maybe its because "everything" is based on Linux. I am not sure i understood the `AccessMode` part of the answer in depth, but maybe i have to use once or twice and come back to your answer then.

Comment: Yes, that is because almost every container image you'll find will be based on linux :) So it underlines almost every workload out there. Also yes, I wanted to introduce `AccessModes` so when you come across them you don't get confused again.

Comment: Hi @zer0 can you please explain what do you mean by AccessMode will be more permissive? Suppose I have a PV with accessmode as ROX while the volume ReadOnly field is set to false on the pod that mounts it. Can the pod write to such a volume?